# Compliling Visual Studio 6 C project from command line

Tags: compilation, visual-studio-6

I'm trying to automate builds of Visual Studio 6 projects (written in C). Everything works fine when I build them from the Visual Studio Development Environment, but I need some help to be able to compile a project (.dsp) or the whole workspace (.dsw) if possible from the command line with command line tools, as this should be done with a batch job for multiple projects at once.

A tutorial or some instructions on how to do this from scratch would be nice...

Comment: Wow, who'd have thought there were so many Visual Studio 6 users still out there!

Comment: Not all by personal choice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command line needs to look something like this:

```
msdev myworkspace.dsw /MAKE "myproject - Win32 Release" /OUT buildlog.txt
```

You'll also need to put the development enironment on your PATH - if it isn't already there, you need to run `c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\Bin\vcvars32.bat` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

```
 msdev FileName [/MAKE "ProjectName – ConfigName | ALL"] [/REBUILD /CLEAN /NORECURSE /OUT LogFile /USEENV]
```

where FileName is the name of your project (.dsp) or **workspace (.dsw)** file.

For example, the following syntax deletes all intermediate files and then builds a project called MyProject:

```
msdev MyProject.dsp /MAKE "MyProject – Win32 Debug" /REBUILD
```

Taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa699274%28v=VS.60%29.aspx)

Keywords for Bing:

> visual studio 6 project command line

and open the first result!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some resources.

[Building a project from the command line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa699274%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

[Working at the Visual Studio command line](http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Using-VS/Working-at-the-Visual-Studio-Command-Line/).

And here is a [forum conversation about using the command line](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/fadabec2-9fea-48c6-ad10-4cf34931b5bd).